# GridView Out of Memory Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, out-of-memory, universal-image-loader

A number of my users (primarily with Samsung devices) are getting an Out of Memory error with my apps that use a gridview.  Note that I can't reproduce this on any of my devices (Nexus)

According to the Universal Image Loader documentation:

```
If you often got OutOfMemoryError in your app using Universal Image Loader then:

Disable caching in memory. If OOM is still occurs then it's a defect of your app.
```

Since I already tried disabling cacheInMemory, apparently I have a defect in the app however I can't see where the problem would be. The grid shows up to 12 items at a time (approximately 1400 in the whole list).  I'm not setting any of the ImageLoaderConfiguration settings, perhaps I should be?

```
private ArrayList<Theme> mThemes;
private static DisplayImageOptions options;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ac_image_grid, container, false);
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_stub)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .cacheInMemory(false)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();
    }
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int result = 0;
        if (mThemes != null) {
            result = mThemes.size();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        Theme theme = mThemes.get(position);

        imageLoader.displayImage(theme.getImageURL(), imageView, options); ***ERROR occurs here

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

ac_image_grid looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_relative"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ptr_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="4dip"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="150dip"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="4dip"
    android:padding="4dip" />
    </uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

item_grid_image:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="ImgDesc"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Edit:  Did a dump off of an emulator (still can't reproduce the error) and had the following memory leak suspects (I have no idea what they mean).

```
 One instance of "android.widget.GridView" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 8,656,352 (15.66%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "android.widget.GridView" loaded by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
android.widget.GridView
```

And

```
One instance of "android.widget.GridView" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 7,214,272 (13.05%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "android.view.View[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
android.view.View[]
android.widget.GridView
```

Purchased one of the affected devices and here is the log:

```
06-28 00:15:28.797    5204-5204/com.test.app.d I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 12.665MB for 1440016-byte allocation
06-28 00:15:28.857    5204-5206/com.test.app.d D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 861K, 13% free 10350K/11783K, paused 2ms+2ms
06-28 00:15:28.937    5204-5228/com.test.app.d I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 13.869MB for 720016-byte allocation
06-28 00:15:28.987    5204-5206/com.test.app.d D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 186K, 5% free 12653K/13255K, paused 2ms+3ms
06-28 00:15:29.037    5204-5230/com.test.app.d I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 17.556MB for 720016-byte allocation
06-28 00:15:29.087    5204-5206/com.test.app.d D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 914K, 10% free 14088K/15495K, paused 1ms+3ms
06-28 00:15:29.127    5204-5230/com.test.app.d I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 19.443MB for 720016-byte allocation
06-28 00:15:29.237    5204-5228/com.test.app.d D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1180K, 9% free 18274K/19911K, paused 24ms
06-28 00:15:29.297    5204-5228/com.test.app.d I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 26.879MB for 720016-byte allocation
06-28 00:15:29.347    5204-5206/com.test.app.d D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 344K, 4% free 22556K/23431K, paused 2ms+2ms
06-28 00:15:29.437    5204-5226/com.test.app.d I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 32.572MB for 720016-byte allocation
06-28 00:15:29.497    5204-5206/com.test.app.d D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 615K, 4% free 28883K/29959K, paused 3ms+4ms
06-28 00:15:29.577    5204-5228/com.test.app.d I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 38.750MB for 720016-byte allocation
06-28 00:15:29.617    5204-5206/com.test.app.d D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 545K, 4% free 33738K/34887K, paused 2ms+3ms
06-28 00:15:29.707    5204-5230/com.test.app.d I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 43.490MB for 720016-byte allocation
06-28 00:15:29.777    5204-5206/com.test.app.d D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 551K, 3% free 40900K/41927K, paused 2ms+3ms
06-28 00:15:29.877    5204-5228/com.test.app.d I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 50.485MB for 720016-byte allocation
06-28 00:15:29.937    5204-5206/com.test.app.d D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 613K, 3% free 45689K/46855K, paused 1ms+4ms
```

Comment: What is your ImageView XML layout?

Comment: Added the XML layouts @NOSTRA

Comment: I can't say what can be a solution for your problem but you can try to add `.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)`. Also you can add approximate `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` in ImageView layout. But anyway you need to reproduce this problem on any device and analyze memory dump with MemoryAnalizer.

Comment: Tried changing the imagescale.  No effect but I pasted a logfile.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late here but I love to solve these kind of problems . First of all does your problem still persists ?

Few suggestions ->

First of all your GC is interrupting more frequently than normal . This will interrupt main thread as well . So we just need to figure out why GC is called again and again .

- First of all check your image sizes. And also you are caching then on disk that may be the problem because every time it is fetching the images from disk.
- Try to use android MAT and hierarchy viewer tools. May be that can help.

I need your answer first to figure out more.

Comment: Each image was a jpg that was about 7kb and displayed in an approximate square of 100dp.  I ended up getting rid of the problem by increasing the size of each image so that there were only about 12-16 on the screen at a time (as opposed to 40ish).  I attributed this to low memory?  I tried using the hierarchy viewer tools but couldn't really find anything useful (but it was the first time I tried).  If you are willing to dig deeper I can pull more info out, let me know.

Comment: sure ...did you try MAT tool as well ?? In Mat you can find objects that are taking most of your memory which leads to GC . To learn more about it you can watch google I/O 2011 video on MAT ...https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk.....I can also look into the code if it is possible for you.

Comment: Yes, I had found that video before and it was extremely helpful.  As far as looking at the code, I'm not sure we could find an easy way to do that.

Comment: ok good...So I guess to help you further I need to look into your code...so is it possible that somehow I can look into your code??

Comment: I can't think of an easy way.  What would you need to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by simply reducing the amount of bitmaps on the screen at any one time for low memory devices.  The solutions posted by Nostra on the github site helped but didn't solve it completely.